# SQL-Get and replace minimum value of a query's field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query in Postgresql :

```
SELECT mq.nombre,sa.nombre,COUNT(DISTINCT(ae.numero_serie)),SUM(im.fin-im.inicio),MIN(pz.fecha_inicio)
FROM item_metraje AS im LEFT JOIN articulo_especificado AS ae ON (im.id_articulo_especificado = ae.id) 
            LEFT JOIN articulo AS a ON (ae.id_articulo = a.id)
            LEFT JOIN serie_articulo AS sa ON (a.id_serie_articulo = sa.id)
            LEFT JOIN reporte_perforacion AS rp ON (rp.id = im.id_reporte_perforacion) 
            LEFT JOIN pozo AS pz ON (pz.id=rp.id_pozo) LEFT JOIN proyecto AS p ON (p.id=pz.id_proyecto) 
            LEFT JOIN maquina_perforacion AS mq ON (mq.id = pz.id_maquina)
WHERE p.id = 2 GROUP BY mq.nombre,sa.nombre
```

and the result is :

[image]

However I want to put the minimum date for the rows that have the same value of the field 'nombre', for example for the value 'JM04' the three rows must have the date 2015-01-25 because it is the minimum value of the three rows.

Excuse me for my English and thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) for this purpose. `MIN(pz.fecha_inicio) over (partition by mq.nombre)`. 

 Therefore the final query is,

```
SELECT z.nombre1,z.nombre2,z.count,z.sum ,MIN(z.date) over (partition by z.nombre1) from
(SELECT mq.nombre as nombre1 ,sa.nombre as nombre2,COUNT(DISTINCT(ae.numero_serie)) as count,SUM(im.fin-im.inicio) as sum ,pz.fecha_inicio as date
FROM item_metraje AS im LEFT JOIN articulo_especificado AS ae ON (im.id_articulo_especificado = ae.id) 
            LEFT JOIN articulo AS a ON (ae.id_articulo = a.id)
            LEFT JOIN serie_articulo AS sa ON (a.id_serie_articulo = sa.id)
            LEFT JOIN reporte_perforacion AS rp ON (rp.id = im.id_reporte_perforacion) 
            LEFT JOIN pozo AS pz ON (pz.id=rp.id_pozo) LEFT JOIN proyecto AS p ON (p.id=pz.id_proyecto) 
            LEFT JOIN maquina_perforacion AS mq ON (mq.id = pz.id_maquina)
WHERE p.id = 2 GROUP BY mq.nombre,sa.nombre)z
```

You can modify this with the help of `order by` or `having` clauses inside window function as you want. 
 I tried this with my own data set. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response,but I worked with your response but I get the following error  'SQL state: 42803', and it means that I must put the field 'pz.fecha_inicio' in 'GROUP BY' or a aggregate function, if I put in 'GROUP BY' the result is not the same of the picture and this has a aggregate function MIN()

Comment: I found the error, first I have to put only the field 'pz.fecha_inicio' and later the field with the Window functions 'MIN(pz.fecha_inicio) OVER (PARTITION BY pz.fecha_inicio)' , but I had to work with nested query for getting the same result that the picture  and this works, thanks